# Order of buttons in navigator.notification.confirm in PhoneGap framework

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using the following piece of code in my PhoneGap app.

```
        function registrationCallBack(button){
            if(button == 2) {
                window.location.href = "login.html";
            }
        }

   navigator.notification.confirm("Are you sure ?", registrationCallBack, "Confirmation", "Cancel, Ok");
```

The order of the buttons is coming properly as "Cancel" and "Ok" in iPhone.
  But for Android the order of buttons are reversed. Its coming as "Ok" and then "Cancel".

As a result the button indices are getting changed in the callback method.

[image: iPhone Screenshot]
[image: android Screenshot]

All suggestions are welcomed :)

Thanks,

Comment: I have created a bug to track this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-889

Comment: Its a "feature" not a bug, according to the Android big brains.

Comment: You might not want to "fix" this, because users expect buttons in certain in places on a particular platform.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following solutions:

```
function showConfirm(message, callback, buttonLabels, title){

    //Set default values if not specified by the user.
    buttonLabels = buttonLabels || 'OK,Cancel';

    title = title || "default title";

    //Use Cordova version of the confirm box if possible.
    if(navigator.notification && navigator.notification.confirm){

            var _callback = function(index){
                if(callback){
                    callback(index == 1);
                }
            };

            navigator.notification.confirm(
                message,      // message
                _callback,    // callback
                title,        // title
                buttonLabels  // buttonName
            );

    //Default to the usual JS confirm method.
    }else{
        invoke(callback, confirm(message));
    }
}
```

And here is how you would use it:

```
var message = "Would you like to proceed?";
var title = "Important Question";

//The first element of this list is the label for positive 
//confirmation i.e. Yes, OK, Proceed.
var buttonLabels = "Yes,No";

var callback = function(yes){
    if(yes){
        alert('Proceed');
    }else{
        alert('Do Not Proceed'); 
    }
};

showConfirm(message, callback, buttonLabels, title);
```

Comment: can you explain `var _callback = function(index){
                if(callback){
                    callback(index == 1);
                }
            };` ?? do this always return 1 to the callback function?

Comment: To callback converts the button index to a boolean value. For example, the yes button is in index 1, so when the user hits the yes button, `index == 1` is equal to `true` etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an Issue. What ever you are getting is native behavior of respective platform. In iOS, "**Cancel**" button will appear on left side and in Android you will get it on Right side. If the problem is only button index, then you can handle it in your code. But you cannot change the sequence of the buttons on screen.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this in iphone. But have tried this in android. I didn't face any such issues with phonegap 1.4.1. Hence i suggest you to upgrade your phonegap version. Issue you faced might be fixed in their new release. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late but I had the same problem, however what I did was change them around so "Cancel" goes where "Ok" is and "Ok" goes where "Cancel" is. That worked for me.